# Why is React Context API mis-behaving in Electron app?

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-context

I'm using the React Context API in my electron app but it appears that a Consumer is picking up the default value from the initial creation of the context instead of the values provided by Provider.

`context.js`

```
import createReactContext from 'create-react-context';

export const LayoutContext = createReactContext({
  isMobile: false,
  toggleSidebar: () => undefined,
});
```

`layout-provider.jsx`

```
export default class LayoutProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isMobile: false,
      toggleSidebar: this.toggleSidebar,
    };
  }

  toggleSidebar = (isOpen) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      isSidebarOpen: _isBoolean(isOpen) ? isOpen : !prevState.isSidebarOpen
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <LayoutContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {this.props.children}
      </LayoutContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

`consumer.jsx`

```
..
<LayoutContext.Consumer>
  {(layoutContext) => <Menu {...props} {...layoutContext} />
  }
</LayoutContext.Consumer>
...
```

`menu.jsx`

```
...
handleToggle = (evt) => {
  evt.preventDefault();
  this.props.toggleSidebar();
};

render() {
  return(
   ...
    <a href='#'
       onClick={this.handleToggle}
    </a>
    ...
  );
}
```

`app.jsx`

```
render() {
...
  <LayoutProvider>
    <Menu />
  </LayoutProvider>
...
}
```

In the Consumer however, I'm seeing that `toggleSidebar` returns undefined.

The same code works in a web app (i.e., toggleSidebar is from the Provider component), but in Electron, I'm seeing this difference.

Comment: Clarify the difference.

Comment: Please show how you are consuming it.

Comment: pasted it, @Vencovsky

Comment: did you find any solution to it?